# Image normalization of an image with large dynamic range

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image of size 144*2209 and its dynamic range is large (from -1108 to 984).

I want to display this image and for that this range needs to be brought into 0 to 255 and for that I need to normalize the image.

Here lies the problem: when such large dynamic range is made compact, the values of pixels after normalization becomes very close to each other such that the image does not show up as it needs to be.

What can be done to resolve this problem???

Here is the link to the [IMAGE](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArfYMunvE-HGga9AfKnN9mmRkfZVoA).

Comment: There are methods for high dynamic range compression. Look at the following paper http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~danix/hdr/hdrc.pdf

Comment: If you only want to display it, you could use `imagesc(img)` which automatically scales the color range.

Comment: I have already tried `imagesc(img)`...no benefit!!

Comment: If you could provide the image in its native format as well (PNG, etc.), would be useful.
Also, if you need to focus on certain intensity ranges, point processing approaches are useful. (https://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS791E/Notes/PointProcess.pdf)

Comment: @crazyGamer This is just a variable (considered to be an image) that contains `double` values which i want to display as an image of the type `uint8`

Comment: Are you displaying this in MATLAB?  `imshow` can handle more than just 8-bit image types.  Did you try increasing the bit resolution (16-bit for example) and displaying it?  Also, try shrinking the dynamic range of your image.  If you know that the intensities are more biased to the higher or lower end, you could use a gamma transformation.  This is quite open-ended and there isn't a single method that will address everything.

Comment: first render histogram plot and then chose what to do .... if there are empty spaces you can discard them ... if the distribution is linear you can bucket linearly if not use more colors for more dense ranges ... I do not use matlab so `*.mat` file is no go for me and therefore can not be more specific ...

Comment: @rayryeng, yes I'm using Matlab and I did try to use 16-bit resolution but no difference. I think it will be really helpful if you can check the type of values in the variable (given above) and tell, what can be done to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a linear transform to change the dynamic range of the original image, **but be aware that you will be modifying the information of the image**.

To do so, for a 8-bit range in Matlab, just use the following snippet :

```
bins = pow2(8); % = range
lin_eq_img = round( (bins - 1) * (img - min_img) / (max_img - min_img) );
```

But it will slightly affect the image :
[image: 8-bit equalization]

Just a few remarks :

- even though your image dynamic range is above a 8-bit depth, it is not considered as 'a large dynamic range'
- depending on what and how you want to do, you might want to consider using the previous linear transform on a 16-bit dynamic in order to avoid losing details (by "squeezing" the pixels values distribution)
- you cannot want the intensity of your pixels values to be within the values given by 8-bit depth per pixel and say that you modified how your image is displayed : **this is not a lossless operation !**
- if you know what you want to enhance, there is plenty of non-linear transformations which could be helpful

Edit :

The 16-bit equalisation version will "keep your shades clearer" (no loss of details) but, of course, the rendered image will take more space. Here is a comparison :

[image: 8-bit vs. 16-bit equalization]

**I would strongly recommend you to perform the histogram normalization on a 2^16 intensity values span, in order to avoid details losses.**

Comment: Thanks for the help!!